# CKEditor and elFinder integration example

Tags: ckeditor, elfinder

I try to follow an instruction  in elfinder.org how to Integration CKEditor with elFinder but not work. is there an example of CKEditor that has been integrated with elFinder, if anybody know, please share it.

Thanks

Comment: Did you manage to find anything? There is no accepted answer so I don't know if you got it working. If you found a way, it would be cool if you shared it with us here as an answer to your own question! :)

Answer (score 1):

I found an example with CKEditor and elFinder here :
http://elrte.org/redmine/attachments/409/elfinder.html

```
$().ready(function() {

   var funcNum = window.location.search.replace(/^.*CKEditorFuncNum=(\d+).*$/, "$1");
   var langCode = window.location.search.replace(/^.*langCode=([a-z]{2}).*$/, "$1");

   $('#finder').elfinder({
      url : 'connectors/php/connector.php',
      lang : langCode,
      editorCallback : function(url) {
         window.opener.CKEDITOR.tools.callFunction(funcNum, url);
         window.close();
      }
   })

})
```

Comment: It seems link in your answer is moved or changed, it heads to fb sign up!

Answer (score -5):

This might be helpful if you are using CKFinder. Try following steps.
1. Download CKEditor and CKFinder. Integrated code may be available on http://dwij.co.in/ckeditor-ckfinder-integration-using-php/
2. Put extracted code of both in one folder inside xampp as below.
3. Create index file (index.html) which will be containing the editor as below code.

```
    <html>
    <head>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckeditor/ckeditor.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="ckfinder/ckfinder.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>CKEditor CKFinder Integration using PHP</h1>
        <textarea id="editor1" name="editor1" rows="10" cols="80"></textarea>
    <script type="text/javascript">
    var editor = CKEDITOR.replace( 'editor1', {
        filebrowserBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html',
        filebrowserImageBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashBrowseUrl : 'ckfinder/ckfinder.html?type=Flash',
        filebrowserUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Files',
        filebrowserImageUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Images',
        filebrowserFlashUploadUrl : 'ckfinder/core/connector/php/connector.php?command=QuickUpload&type=Flash'
    });
    CKFinder.setupCKEditor( editor, '../' );
    </script>
    </body>
    </html>
```

so your folder structure will be something like this:

```
htdocs
|_integrated
    |_ckeditor
    |   |_config.js
    |   |_...
    |_ckfinder
    |   |_config.php
    |   |_...
    |_uploads
    |_index.html
```

1. Now open file config.php inside ckfinder & make following changes:

   ```
   function CheckAuthentication() {
       // WARNING : DO NOT simply return "true". By doing so, you are allowing
       // "anyone" to upload and list the files in your server. You must implement
       // some kind of session validation here. Even something very simple as...
       // return isset($_SESSION['IsAuthorized']) && $_SESSION['IsAuthorized'];
       return true; // not good option though; go for sessions
   }
   $baseUrl = 'http://localhost/integrated/uploads/';
   $enabled = true;
   $config['SecureImageUploads'] = false;
   $config['ChmodFolders'] = 0777 ;
   ```
2. Now open url `http://localhost/integrated/` and try uploading image.

Comment: -1 Sorry, but this question was specifically about not CKFinder, but Elfinder, which would take the place of CKFinder.